# Find the user with Direct Access in SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

As I am trying to find the user who has Direct Access permission in the site and also there is some checkbox called "Share Everything in this folder, even items with unique permissions." which is available at the permission page of the SharePoint Item.

[image: Image for Reference]

As I need solution for finding the user with the permission for Direct Access and also the user has this checkbox checked or not. It Could be better to get these data using Graph API or CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use SharePoint CSOM (Client Side Object Model) as it provides a powerful way to interact with SharePoint resources including permissions. You can use C# to write a console application or script to achieve this.

```
RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignments = web.RoleAssignments;
clientContext.Load(roleAssignments, ras => ras.Include(ra => ra.Member, ra => ra.RoleDefinitionBindings));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (RoleAssignment roleAssignment in roleAssignments)
{
    Principal principal = roleAssignment.Member;
    foreach (RoleDefinition roleDefinition in roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
    {
        if (roleDefinition.Name == "Direct Access")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"User: {principal.LoginName}");
            // Check the checkbox state here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response Raytheon. As per my evaluation I got the RoleDefinitionBinding.Name like "Full Control", "Contribute", etc. but I didn't received anything named like 'Direct Access". And there is no role like "Direct Access" in Role Definition. So is there any other solution that may match with my requirement?